# Strong IR transmitter for pi 3

Tags: pi-3, lirc

I've currently built an IR remote for my tv using a raspberry pi 3 and [https://www.amazon.com/Infrared-Shield-for-Raspberry-Pi/dp/B00K2IICKK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K2IICKK)

I cannot get the same signal strength from the pi remote compared to the original TV remote which works from several odd positions (above, below, sides of the TV).

Is there different hardware or even a software solution for the pi to improve IR transmission.

Comment: Perhaps ask the maker/vendor?

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic methods of augmenting IR remote control signals:

- Increasing transmission power.
- Concentrating transmission power.
- Diffusing the transmission beam.

Increasing transmission power is not likely to work well, since the IR LED has a particular breakdown voltage and current.  So, we are left with concentrating transmission power and/or diffusing the beam.

On mass produced remotes, usually there's a reflector backing the IR LED which helps concentrate the signal.  This reflector can be a simple recess in the casing or a separate mounting attachment. Some also have diffusing lens which decrease directional signal control but increase the angle range.